# Installing Nvidia Drivers in 12.04

Tags: 12.04, gnome, nvidia, package-management, themes

1> I have been fed up trying to install nvidia graphic drivers. After the installation ubuntu starts looking ugly, the taskbar or the sidebar doesnt remain the same as before. The window close button or minimize button disappears.

2> Which packages should should i install to make my desktop look the best? Like gnome2 or cinnamon.

3> If anyone out there have a good knowledge of ubuntu please share what things should i install after installation of ubuntu.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Welcome to Askubuntu.  We recommend that you ask the questions separately; one question for one question only.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to install the nvidia driver by launching `jockey-gtk` or simply by searching "drivers" in the dash.

If it that does not work, you can try to search your device in [Nvidia's site](http://nvidia.com) , as they might have more resent drivers.

I would recommend you to install the `ubuntu-restricted-extras` package (to play the most common audio files, view flash videos, etc), altough there are open source alternatives.
I also recommend you to install the `ttf-mscorefonts-installer` package, so most webpages and documents can be viewed properly.

You should check this [site](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/04/things-to-tweak-after-installing-ubuntu.html) for things that you can do after installing Ubuntu.

Good Luck!