# Install NVIDIA Drivers

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics

I installed Ubuntu 13.04, but after the reboot theres only a black screen with the blinking bar on the top left. I found, that one possible solution is that the video drivers are not installed, so i tried it (the weird thing is that "try ubuntu without installing" works perfectly fine). So i downloaded the .run file, but it's always saying "seems like you're running a X Server" blahblah. I searched for maybe 2 hours for the solution, but none of the ones i found worked for me. Can anybody please help me? PS: I'm pretty new to Ubuntu...

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/questions/66328/how-do-i-install-latest-nvidia-drivers-by-hand

Comment: Ubuntu **32-bit** or **64-bit** ?

Comment: Possible duplicate (might be to outdated):http://askubuntu.com/questions/72155/ubuntu-10-04-nvidia-drivers

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/questions/112732/how-do-i-install-nvidia-drivers-in-ubuntu-11-10

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/questions/47506/how-do-i-install-extra-drivers

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/questions/150825/installing-nvidia-driver

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/questions/185338/installing-nvidia-drivers-in-12-04

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/questions/286767/install-nvidia-drivers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- There is a bug with nvidia and the stock 3.8.0-19 kernel in ubuntu 13.04 use the [mainline kernel](https://github.com/GM-Script-Writer-62850/Ubuntu-Mainline-Kernel-Updater#readme)

  - Not doing this can result in not being able to boot
- Install the driver by running `sudo apt-get install -y nvidia-313-updates nvidia-settings-313-updates`

  - If you want the beta driver use the [xorg edgers](https://launchpad.net/~xorg-edgers/+archive/ppa) ppa, then install `nvidia-319 nvidia-settings-319`

    ```
    sudo apt-add-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa -y; sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get upgrade -y; sudo apt-get install nvidia-319 nvidia-settings-319 -y
    ```

Comment: I fail at the first step, i tried it with the .zip file and the file named "install" in the .zip file, but either way it says: "bash: /*path*/install: Permission denied" And i even logged in with root user     EDIT: I needed to change the permissions :D

Comment: Use the terminal commands work every time :) (the script will ask for your password when needed) When someones says /path/to/ that means the same thing as foo/bar or fill in the blank

Comment: Now it says "Package nvidia-settings-313 can't be found." (I hope i translated it correctly :D)

Comment: fixed: I missed "-updates" when i typed that one (see answer); don't forget to install the new kernel after running the last command in the instructions (run `/tmp/kernel-update`)

Comment: Now there's something weird... After telling me i need 209 MB free space on my hdd it asks me if i would like to continue. when i say "y" it says "cancelled"........ And i dit install the new kernel :D

Comment: did is say Y or y it could be case sensitive, I edited the install line to make it not ask and just do it

Comment: ok, thanks a lot! let's check if ubuntu starts now :)

Comment: Gosh, still stuck on the black screen. But thanks anyways

Comment: You did install the kernel using the script that the installer made for you right, the one it told you do install if you wanted the new kernel: `/tmp/kernel-update` if not there is your problem; Computer model#?

Comment: I did that. But i posted a new thread for that because now i know that the problem is not the drivers. But i would apprechiate if you could help me in the other thread (http://askubuntu.com/questions/286797/booting-problem-with-ubuntu-13-04)

Answer (score 0):

nvidia has now different packages - so it happens, that certain graphics-card
is only working best with a certain package. sometimes it lasts longer then, until
one has found the proper package for the certain card.

e.g. optimus CUDA - they are not supported by included nvidia-packages of Debian/Ubuntu fully - instead they seem to be fully supported only by package:

NVIDIA_CUDA_SDK_1.1_Beta_Linux.run