# Booting Problem with ubuntu 13.04

Tags: boot

I installed Ubuntu 13.04 via DVD and everytime i restart, theres just a black screen bith the blinking cursor. I tried updating my video driver, but that did not help. i tried it with ubuntu 12.something, too but there was the same problem. I searched 3 hours straight and tried everzthing i found but nothing yet helped. I have the NVIDIA GeForce GTX 260 along with an asus M5A78L - M LX mainboard and the AMD FX-6100.

Answer (score 0):

Without more information, this sounds like a boot problem rather than a particular graphics card issue.

Try using:

http://www.ubuntugeek.com/boot-repair-simple-tool-to-repair-frequent-boot-problems.html

to resolve the issue, this will also generate a pastebin link which you can paste here and someone will be able to point you in the right direction.